# A game of drawing marbles

Tags: probability

There are 2 people A & B and a bag full of 10 equal marbles. Person A specifies a number $( 1 \leq k \leq 10 )$. Then:

1. B chooses $k$ marbles from the bag.
2. Among these $k$ marbles B marks those which hasn't been marked yet. (clearly at first time B draws $k$ marbles, all of them are unmarked).
3. Then B puts them ($k$ marbles) back in the bag.
4. B does steps 1 to 3 for 10 times.

After B is finished, A chooses $k$ marbles from the bag. What is the probability that all $k$ marbles are marked?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered this problem but when B does the steps say once or twice? Or maybe three times?

Comment: Examples are certainly a good idea.  If, say, $A$ specifies $k=10$ the problem is trivial.  Can you handle the case $k=1$?

Comment: Looks like the question this was closed as a duplicate of got deleted by the roomba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each marble not to be chosen in a round probability is $\frac{10-k}{10}$. After 10 rounds probability that is not marked is $(\frac{10-k}{10})^{10}$.

So for each of the $k$ marbles player A has chosen, probability that it was marked is $1-(\frac{10-k}{10})^{10}$.

Now if we were naive we would say the needed probability is $(1-(\frac{10-k}{10})^{10})^k$. It is the probability if those outcomes were all independent which is not the case.

We have to calculate probability for each set of marbles to avoid being marked.

So for $m$ particular marbles not to be chosen in a round (none of them to be marked) probability is ${10-m \choose k}/{10 \choose k}$, $1\le m \le 10-k$ (choose some $k$ marbles not being in the set)

In the end we can use inclusion–exclusion principle, so probability we are looking for is:
$$P=1+\sum_{m=1}^{min(k,10-k)}(-1)^m {k \choose m}{10-m \choose k}^{10}/{10 \choose k}^{10}$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (or if this is irrelevant) but doesn't this assume that each round is independent of the other?

Comment: Oh, let me rethink because I think I misunderstood your solution!

Comment: @JihoonKang From point of view of an unmarked marble previous rounds didn't affect it. Cheers

Comment: yes, apologies I have misunderstood the first part of your solution and it led me to think that it was wrong, but it seems that I was wrong!

Comment: @JihoonKang I see. I better write "to be chosen in a round" than "to be marked in a round". Thanks

Comment: It seems clearer now thank you